# Use only Wifi instead of bluetooth when in discovery mode in "nearby connection"

Tags: android, google-nearby

Is there a way to force "nearby connection" to use only Wifi P2P or any other way(except hotspot) instead of using Bluetooth when the App is in discovery mode? If so, then how?

I can't find anything related to this in their docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. May I ask why you want that feature?

Comment: Having Bluetooth icon popup will make the user feel that my app is consuming battery but when using wifi (P2P) there is no icon shown so the user will feel that my app is magical. It's not something important but having it would be better. Btw is the source code of "nearby" available for open source?

Comment: I see. I can't say that's a use-case we want to support, because we do want users to be informed about what their phone is up to. Combating that misconception that Bluetooth = battery drain is a separate issue.

Comment: No, Nearby is not open source. There is talk of open sourcing the protocol, but the actual code is proprietary.

Comment: How are you guys accepting Bluetooth and WiFi direct connection request (that usually needs user intervention in a system generated dialog)? Or are you using some other method to send data? I am not opening a new question because I wanted to ask it from a "nearby" developer only.

Comment: Google Play Services is a system app, so it has some advantages other apps don't have